# Android Facebook Login Prolem

Tags: android, facebook

I just followed the steps in this website:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

The result on my simulator is correct(It will show "Hello + name").

But when I test my application on my phone,

It will show nothing.

Can Anybody tell me what's wrong,thanks!!

Following is my code:

```
  @Override

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // start Facebook Login

    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

      // callback when session changes state

      @Override

      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        if (session.isOpened()) {

          // make request to the /me API

          Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object

            @Override

            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {
                TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
```